# Android Root of all Activities and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

How can I implement `"dispatchTouchEvent(...){}"` on root of my android app instead of each of activities, because I want to get when my application get sleep or in pause state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a BaseActivity where you implement it and all your activities inherit from BaseActivity:

```
class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    dispatchTouchEvent() {...}
}

class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of central handling would be possible if all your activities are extended from single activity in your project. 
Say, AppBaseActivity contains most general functionality & all others extend it. So, events can be traced down to this AppBaseActivity.

I can't predict any other way to achieve the result you want to get.